# Ample SDK vs Raphael

Tags: javascript, charts, svg, raphael

We're evaluating a SVG/VML library to use in out reporting project. Does anyone have experience in using both Ample SDK and Raphael and can provide inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends on your needs, since the two target very different aims.

Ample SDK offers a fully equipped framework for dealing with virtually every aspect of the Graphic User Interface, inter alia an SVG (1.1) interface. Note that it's currently in beta (0.9.3), and after visiting the [Ample SDK website](http://www.amplesdk.com/), it seems that the current release is not lacking problems.

Raphaël is aiming at providing a user friendly API for dealing with vector graphics rendering on a wide range of browsers. It's doing very well at it IMO, but that's its sole purpose. It is pretty mature (v. 2.1.0 at the moment) and maintained (see the [Raphaël github](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael)).

If all you're looking for are custom painted shapes and backward compatibility for IE - definitely go for Raphaël, but if you need an all-propose, extensible solution - use Ample SDK.

*You should note that Raphaël uses VML on older rendering engines, thus supporting IE 8 and 7, while [Ample's SVG pack is compatible with modern browsers only](http://www.amplesdk.com/about/compatibility/).*

Comment: g.raphael is not maintained any more by its creator: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael